# Building a list in prolog

Tags: list, recursion, prolog

im a beginner on prolog, and I am trying to return a list of results. 
Say i have items belonging to a person ie.

items(person1,apple).

items(person1,orange).

I want to be able to create a function that can return the list of items belonging to that person.
At the moment I have:

getitems(Person,Result):-items(Person,N),Result is N.

This only returns the first item.
How can i get it to return a list of all the items that belong to the person?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asked plenty of times, the correct nomenclature is "Finding all solution to a goal", for example, from the SWI-Prolog implementation, [finding all solutions](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=section%282,%274.30%27,swi%28%27/doc/Manual/allsolutions.html%27%29%29).

In short,

```
bagof(Item, items(person1, Item), Items).
```

The predicates in this section, `findall`, `bagof`, and `setof` all behave slightly differently and have their uses. There is plenty of examples on Stackoverflow on how to use each of them.